# Removing (' or [] ) from Dataframe insert turfpy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I have Data in a Dataframe but when using said Data in a function it won't let me, because everything in the Dataframe is has [] around them which when exported means the Items have '' around them

```
print df_total

     index    Observation Date      Reporting Date                      Name                   E-Mail Profile-ID  ...    Subregion    Latitude   Longitude Elevation Incline Aspect
0        0  [2021-04-25 11:00]  [2021-04-26 19:34]       [Robert Kniewasser]  [rkniewasser@petzl.com]    [15444]  ...  [Nordalpen]  [47.64627]  [14.19269]   [2160m]   [35°]    [N]
1        1  [2021-03-25 09:30]  [2021-03-25 19:04]  [Herbert K. / Winter C.]   [herbert.kerbl@aon.at]    [15155]  ...   [Voralpen]  [47.80251]  [14.36570]   [1420m]   [42°]   [NE]
```

I tried:

```
    df_total['Latitude'] = df_total['Latitude'].str.get(0)
    df_total['Latitude'] = df_total['Latitude'].str[0]
    df_total['Latitude'] = df_total['Latitude'].str.strip('[]').astype(float)
```

This is the issue:

```
print([df_total.at[0, 'Latitude'], df_total.at[0, 'Longitude']])

[['47.64627'], ['14.19269']]
```

I need to get rid of the ('' and [])

I am trying to import the data into a turfpy function and it can't work with the ''

```
raise ValueError("%r is not a JSON compliant number" % coord)
ValueError: '47.64627' is not a JSON compliant number
```

.

```
f1 = Feature(geometry=Point([df_total.at[0, 'Latitude'], df_total.at[0, 'Longitude']]))
```

should equal to

```
f1 = Feature(geometry=Point([47.64627, 14.19269]))
```

Test code here:

```
from logging import log
import string
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
from pandas.io.formats.format import DataFrameFormatter
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import webdriver_manager
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from numpy.core.fromnumeric import var
from numpy.lib.utils import source
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.indexing import check_bool_indexer
import os
import re



dir_list = os.listdir()
print(dir_list)

#Functions

def googlepopupaccept():
    if WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='L2AGLb']"))):
        #driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'consent.google.com')]"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='L2AGLb']"))).click()
        
#Chrome Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
# options.add_argument('headless')
# options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
# options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--incognito")

#Search for input in Google accept cookies
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
googlepopupaccept()

#Open Lawis
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= 'chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
googlemaps = driver.get("https://www.lawis.at")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@title="Profiles"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@class="button_subnav active"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="filter_set_two"]'))).click()
country_search = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="chosen-search-input default"]')))
country_search.click()
country_search.send_keys('Österreich' + Keys.ENTER)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="region_chosen"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="chosen-search-input default"]'))).send_keys('Oberösterreich' + Keys.ENTER)

#Button Submit Click and open list to see details
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="filter_down"]/form/div/div[2]/button'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchText"]'))).click()





#Click on each List Item and store data

#Variable subject to loop change +1
url_lawis_list_item0 = '/html/body/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]'
position = 56

#Make list from string
url_lawis_list_item_list = list(url_lawis_list_item0)
print(url_lawis_list_item_list)

#Changing variable for loop
tobechanged_index = int(url_lawis_list_item_list[position])

#Variable lists of all data entries
lst_total_info_date = []
lst_total_info_reporting_date = []
lst_total_info_name = []
lst_total_info_email = []
lst_total_info_id = []
lst_total_info_location = []
lst_total_info_country = []
lst_total_info_region = []
lst_total_info_subregion = []
lst_total_info_latitude = []
lst_total_info_longitude = []
lst_total_info_elevation = []
lst_total_info_incline = []
lst_total_info_aspect = []


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, url_lawis_list_item0))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tab_info"]'))).click()

#for testing purposes change while True: to "while tobechanged_index < 3"
while tobechanged_index < 3:

    print(tobechanged_index)
    
    #Click on column
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, url_lawis_list_item0))).click()


    #Change item in list +1 
    changed_index = int(url_lawis_list_item_list[position]) +1
    url_lawis_list_item_list[position] = changed_index
    print(url_lawis_list_item_list)
    
    #make string out of list
    empty_string = ""
    for i in url_lawis_list_item_list:
        empty_string += str(i) + ""
        
    url_lawis_list_item0 = empty_string
    print(url_lawis_list_item0)
    
    tobechanged_index = changed_index
    
    #Make list out of elements
    lst = []
    info_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_date"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_date)
    info_reporting_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_reporting_date"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_reporting_date)
    info_name = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_name"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_name)
    info_email = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_email"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_email)
    info_id = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_id"]'))).text 
    lst.append(info_id)
    info_location = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_location"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_location)
    info_country = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_country"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_country)
    info_region = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_region"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_region)
    info_subregion = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_subregion"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_subregion)
    info_latitude = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_latitude"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_latitude)
    info_longitude = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_longitude"]'))).text 
    lst.append(info_longitude)
    info_elevation = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_seehoehe"]'))).text 
    lst.append(info_elevation)
    info_incline = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_incline"]'))).text 
    lst.append(info_incline)
    info_aspect = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_aspect"]'))).text 
    lst.append(info_aspect)
    
    print(info_date)
    print(info_reporting_date)
    print(info_name)
    print(info_email)
    print(info_id)
    print(info_location)
    print(info_country)
    print(info_region)
    print(info_subregion)
    print(info_latitude)
    print(info_longitude)
    print(info_elevation)
    print(info_incline)
    print(info_aspect)
    
    print(lst)
    
    
    data_entry_date = [info_date]
    lst_total_info_date.append(data_entry_date)
    data_entry__reporting_date = [info_reporting_date]
    lst_total_info_reporting_date.append(data_entry__reporting_date)
    data_entry_name = [info_name]
    lst_total_info_name.append(data_entry_name)
    data_entry_email = [info_email]
    lst_total_info_email.append(data_entry_email)
    data_entry_id = [info_id]
    lst_total_info_id.append(data_entry_id)
    data_entry_location = [info_location]
    lst_total_info_location.append(data_entry_location)
    data_entry_country = [info_country]
    lst_total_info_country.append(data_entry_country)
    data_entry_region = [info_region]
    lst_total_info_region.append(data_entry_region)
    data_entry_subregion = [info_subregion]
    lst_total_info_subregion.append(data_entry_subregion)
    data_entry_latitude = [info_latitude]
    lst_total_info_latitude.append(data_entry_latitude)
    data_entry_longitude = [info_longitude]
    lst_total_info_longitude.append(data_entry_longitude)
    data_entry_elevation = [info_elevation]
    lst_total_info_elevation.append(data_entry_elevation)
    data_entry_incline = [info_incline]
    lst_total_info_incline.append(data_entry_incline)
    data_entry_aspect = [info_aspect]
    lst_total_info_aspect.append(data_entry_aspect)
    
    
    #Click on column
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, url_lawis_list_item0))).click()
    #scroll down once
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.DOWN)

    
#combined list of all data entries for dataframe 
lst_total = [lst_total_info_date, lst_total_info_reporting_date, lst_total_info_name, lst_total_info_email, lst_total_info_id,
                lst_total_info_location, lst_total_info_country, lst_total_info_region, lst_total_info_subregion, lst_total_info_latitude, lst_total_info_longitude,
                lst_total_info_elevation, lst_total_info_incline, lst_total_info_aspect]


# Initialise empty Dataframe with column names 
import numpy as np
df0 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((100, 14)))
df0.columns = ['Observation Date', 'Reporting Date', 'Name', 'E-Mail', 'Profile-ID', 'Place', 'Country', 'Region', 'Subregion', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Elevation', 'Incline', 'Aspect', ]
print(df0)


# Build Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(lst_total).transpose()
df.columns = ['Observation Date', 'Reporting Date', 'Name', 'E-Mail', 'Profile-ID', 'Place', 'Country', 'Region', 'Subregion', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Elevation', 'Incline', 'Aspect', ]
print(df)

dataframes = [df, df0]
df_total = pd.concat(dataframes)
df_total = df_total.reset_index()
print(df_total)

# print(lst_total_observation, lst_total_reporting, lst_total_name, lst_total_email,
#       lst_total_profile, lst_total_place, lst_total_region, lst_total_location,
#       lst_total_elevation, lst_total_incline, lst_total_aspect, lst_total_latitude, lst_total_longitude)



search_input_lang_long = '47.6236, 14.346'


import json
from turfpy.measurement import nearest_point
from geojson import Point, Feature, FeatureCollection

f1_lat_long = [float(df_total.at[0, 'Latitude'][0]), float(df_total.at[0, 'Longitude'][0])]
print(f1_lat_long)
f2_lat_long = [float(df_total.at[1, 'Latitude'][0]), float(df_total.at[1, 'Longitude'][0])]
print(f2_lat_long)

f1 = Feature(geometry=Point(f1_lat_long))
f2 = Feature(geometry=Point(f2_lat_long))
f3 = Feature(geometry=Point([df_total.at[2, 'Latitude'], df_total.at[2, 'Longitude']]))
f4 = Feature(geometry=Point([df_total.at[3, 'Latitude'], df_total.at[3, 'Longitude']]))
f5 = Feature(geometry=Point([df_total.at[3, 'Latitude'], df_total.at[3, 'Longitude']]))


fc = FeatureCollection([f1, f2, f3, f4, f5])


print(json.dumps(nearest_point(search_input_lang_long ,fc), indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

***EDIT-----------------------------------***

After implementing the fixes as stated underneath:
Test code looks like this now:

```
from logging import log
import string
from geojson.geometry import Geometry
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
from pandas.io.formats.format import DataFrameFormatter
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import webdriver_manager
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from numpy.core.fromnumeric import var
from numpy.lib.utils import source
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.indexing import check_bool_indexer
import os
import re



dir_list = os.listdir()
print(dir_list)

#Functions

def googlepopupaccept():
    if WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='L2AGLb']"))):
        #driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'consent.google.com')]"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='L2AGLb']"))).click()
        
#Chrome Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
# options.add_argument('headless')
# options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
# options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--incognito")

#Search for input in Google accept cookies
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
googlepopupaccept()

#Open Lawis
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= 'chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
googlemaps = driver.get("https://www.lawis.at")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@title="Profiles"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@class="button_subnav active"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="filter_set_two"]'))).click()
country_search = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="chosen-search-input default"]')))
country_search.click()
country_search.send_keys('Österreich' + Keys.ENTER)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="region_chosen"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="chosen-search-input default"]'))).send_keys('Oberösterreich' + Keys.ENTER)

#Button Submit Click and open list to see details
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="filter_down"]/form/div/div[2]/button'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchText"]'))).click()





#Click on each List Item and store data

#Variable subject to loop change +1
url_lawis_list_item0 = '/html/body/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]'
position = 56

#Make list from string
url_lawis_list_item_list = list(url_lawis_list_item0)
print(url_lawis_list_item_list)

#Changing variable for loop
tobechanged_index = int(url_lawis_list_item_list[position])

#Variable lists of all data entries
lst_total_info_date = []
lst_total_info_reporting_date = []
lst_total_info_name = []
lst_total_info_email = []
lst_total_info_id = []
lst_total_info_location = []
lst_total_info_country = []
lst_total_info_region = []
lst_total_info_subregion = []
lst_total_info_latitude = []
lst_total_info_longitude = []
lst_total_info_elevation = []
lst_total_info_incline = []
lst_total_info_aspect = []


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, url_lawis_list_item0))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tab_info"]'))).click()

#for testing purposes change while True: to "while tobechanged_index < 3"
while tobechanged_index < 3:

    print(tobechanged_index)
    
    #Click on column
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, url_lawis_list_item0))).click()


    #Change item in list +1 
    changed_index = int(url_lawis_list_item_list[position]) +1
    url_lawis_list_item_list[position] = changed_index
    print(url_lawis_list_item_list)
    
    #make string out of list
    empty_string = ""
    for i in url_lawis_list_item_list:
        empty_string += str(i) + ""
        
    url_lawis_list_item0 = empty_string
    print(url_lawis_list_item0)
    
    tobechanged_index = changed_index
    
    #Make list out of elements
    lst = []
    info_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_date"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_date)
    info_reporting_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_reporting_date"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_reporting_date)
    info_name = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_name"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_name)
    info_email = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_email"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_email)
    info_id = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_id"]'))).text 
    lst.append(info_id)
    info_location = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_location"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_location)
    info_country = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_country"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_country)
    info_region = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_region"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_region)
    info_subregion = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_subregion"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_subregion)
    info_latitude = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_latitude"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_latitude)
    info_longitude = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_longitude"]'))).text 
    lst.append(info_longitude)
    info_elevation = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_seehoehe"]'))).text 
    lst.append(info_elevation)
    info_incline = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_incline"]'))).text 
    lst.append(info_incline)
    info_aspect = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_aspect"]'))).text 
    lst.append(info_aspect)
    
    print(info_date)
    print(info_reporting_date)
    print(info_name)
    print(info_email)
    print(info_id)
    print(info_location)
    print(info_country)
    print(info_region)
    print(info_subregion)
    print(info_latitude)
    print(info_longitude)
    print(info_elevation)
    print(info_incline)
    print(info_aspect)
    
    print(lst)
    
    
    data_entry_date = info_date
    lst_total_info_date.append(data_entry_date)
    data_entry__reporting_date = info_reporting_date
    lst_total_info_reporting_date.append(data_entry__reporting_date)
    data_entry_name = info_name
    lst_total_info_name.append(data_entry_name)
    data_entry_email = info_email
    lst_total_info_email.append(data_entry_email)
    data_entry_id = info_id
    lst_total_info_id.append(data_entry_id)
    data_entry_location = info_location
    lst_total_info_location.append(data_entry_location)
    data_entry_country = info_country
    lst_total_info_country.append(data_entry_country)
    data_entry_region = info_region
    lst_total_info_region.append(data_entry_region)
    data_entry_subregion = info_subregion
    lst_total_info_subregion.append(data_entry_subregion)
    data_entry_latitude = info_latitude
    lst_total_info_latitude.append(data_entry_latitude)
    data_entry_longitude = info_longitude
    lst_total_info_longitude.append(data_entry_longitude)
    data_entry_elevation = info_elevation
    lst_total_info_elevation.append(data_entry_elevation)
    data_entry_incline = info_incline
    lst_total_info_incline.append(data_entry_incline)
    data_entry_aspect = info_aspect
    lst_total_info_aspect.append(data_entry_aspect)
    
    
    #Click on column
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, url_lawis_list_item0))).click()
    #scroll down once
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.DOWN)

    
#combined list of all data entries for dataframe 
lst_total = [lst_total_info_date, lst_total_info_reporting_date, lst_total_info_name, lst_total_info_email, lst_total_info_id,
                lst_total_info_location, lst_total_info_country, lst_total_info_region, lst_total_info_subregion, lst_total_info_latitude, lst_total_info_longitude,
                lst_total_info_elevation, lst_total_info_incline, lst_total_info_aspect]
    
    
    # Initialise empty Dataframe with column names 
import numpy as np
df0 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((100, 14)))
df0.columns = ['Observation Date', 'Reporting Date', 'Name', 'E-Mail', 'Profile-ID', 'Place', 'Country', 'Region', 'Subregion', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Elevation', 'Incline', 'Aspect']
print(df0)
print(df0.dtypes)


# Build Dataframe with Website data
df = pd.DataFrame(lst_total).transpose()
df.columns = ['Observation Date', 'Reporting Date', 'Name', 'E-Mail', 'Profile-ID', 'Place', 'Country', 'Region', 'Subregion', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Elevation', 'Incline', 'Aspect']
print(df)

# Initialize Dataframe combined 0 and Data
dataframes = [df, df0]
df_total = pd.concat(dataframes)
df_total = df_total.reset_index()
print(df_total)

# Dataframe with lat_long
df_lat_long = pd.DataFrame(df_total['Latitude'].astype(str) + ', ' + df_total['Longitude'].astype(str))
df_lat_long.columns = ['lat_long']
print(df_lat_long)

# print(lst_total_observation, lst_total_reporting, lst_total_name, lst_total_email,
#       lst_total_profile, lst_total_place, lst_total_region, lst_total_location,
#       lst_total_elevation, lst_total_incline, lst_total_aspect, lst_total_latitude, lst_total_longitude)






import json
from turfpy.measurement import nearest_point
from geojson import Point, Feature, FeatureCollection

search_input_lang_long = Feature(geometry=Point([47.6236, 14.346]))

f1 = Feature(geometry=Point(df_lat_long.at[0, 'lat_long']))
f2 = Feature(geometry=Point(df_lat_long.at[1, 'lat_long']))
f3 = Feature(geometry=Point(df_lat_long.at[2, 'lat_long']))
f4 = Feature(geometry=Point(df_lat_long.at[3, 'lat_long']))
f5 = Feature(geometry=Point(df_lat_long.at[4, 'lat_long']))


fc = FeatureCollection([f1, f2, f3, f4, f5])


print(json.dumps(nearest_point(search_input_lang_long ,fc), indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

I am getting a new error output which looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Green\Dropbox\Coding\Skitouring_app\Lawis.at_TESTING.py", line 252, in <module>
    f1 = Feature(geometry=Point(df_lat_long.at[0, 'lat_long']))
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\geojson\geometry.py", line 31, in __init__
    self["coordinates"] = self.clean_coordinates(
  File "C:\Users\Green\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\geojson\geometry.py", line 55, in clean_coordinates
    raise ValueError("%r is not a JSON compliant number" % coord)
ValueError: '4' is not a JSON compliant number
```

Turpy [enter link description here](https://turfpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/measurements/nearest_point.html)

Turfpy example Code

```
import json
from turfpy.measurement import nearest_point
from geojson import Point, Feature, FeatureCollection
f1 = Feature(geometry=Point([28.96991729736328,41.01190001748873]))
f2 = Feature(geometry=Point([28.948459, 41.024204]))
f3 = Feature(geometry=Point([28.938674, 41.013324]))
fc = FeatureCollection([f1, f2 ,f3])
t = Feature(geometry=Point([28.973865, 41.011122]))

print(json.dumps(nearest_point(t ,fc), indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

The reason why there are many 0.0 coordinates is because of the way I need it to work:
In short the amount of data rows I get from the website is depended on when I run the code / how many entries are in the website. Since turfpy only works with a set amount of variables (f1, f2, f3, etc.) I needed a way to have a fixed preset amount of variables. I know for a fact that it wont get over 100 entries on the website. So I though I could make a Dataframe with the data from the website, then append another with '0.0's and use those as my variables for turfpy. (So that I always have 100 rows that have data, even if its just a lot of 0.0s). The nearest point would never be lat 0.0 long 0.0, it would always be some point from the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lines like...

```
data_entry_latitude = [info_latitude]
```

which should be...

```
data_entry_latitude = info_latitude
```

I may have messed up your `webdriver.Chrome()` bit though if you need a path - I've got the file in the same directory as the script). However...

**Try:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import os
import json
from turfpy.measurement import nearest_point
from geojson import Point, Feature, FeatureCollection

dir_list = os.listdir()
# print(dir_list)

#Functions

def googlepopupaccept():
    if WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='L2AGLb']"))):
        #driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'consent.google.com')]"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='L2AGLb']"))).click()
        
#Chrome Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
# options.add_argument('headless')
# options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
# options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--incognito")

#Search for input in Google accept cookies
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
googlepopupaccept()

#Open Lawis
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= 'chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
googlemaps = driver.get("https://www.lawis.at")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@title="Profiles"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@class="button_subnav active"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="filter_set_two"]'))).click()
country_search = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="chosen-search-input default"]')))
country_search.click()
country_search.send_keys('Österreich' + Keys.ENTER)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="region_chosen"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="chosen-search-input default"]'))).send_keys('Oberösterreich' + Keys.ENTER)

#Button Submit Click and open list to see details
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="filter_down"]/form/div/div[2]/button'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchText"]'))).click()


#Click on each List Item and store data

#Variable subject to loop change +1
url_lawis_list_item0 = '/html/body/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]'
position = 56

#Make list from string
url_lawis_list_item_list = list(url_lawis_list_item0)
# print(url_lawis_list_item_list)

#Changing variable for loop
tobechanged_index = int(url_lawis_list_item_list[position])

#Variable lists of all data entries
lst_total_info_date = []
lst_total_info_reporting_date = []
lst_total_info_name = []
lst_total_info_email = []
lst_total_info_id = []
lst_total_info_location = []
lst_total_info_country = []
lst_total_info_region = []
lst_total_info_subregion = []
lst_total_info_latitude = []
lst_total_info_longitude = []
lst_total_info_elevation = []
lst_total_info_incline = []
lst_total_info_aspect = []


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, url_lawis_list_item0))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tab_info"]'))).click()

#for testing purposes change while True: to "while tobechanged_index < 3"
while tobechanged_index < 3:

#     print(tobechanged_index)
    
    #Click on column
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, url_lawis_list_item0))).click()


    #Change item in list +1 
    changed_index = int(url_lawis_list_item_list[position]) +1
    url_lawis_list_item_list[position] = changed_index
#     print(url_lawis_list_item_list)
    
    #make string out of list
    empty_string = ""
    for i in url_lawis_list_item_list:
        empty_string += str(i) + ""
        
    url_lawis_list_item0 = empty_string
#     print(url_lawis_list_item0)
    
    tobechanged_index = changed_index
    
    #Make list out of elements
    lst = []
    info_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_date"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_date)
    info_reporting_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_reporting_date"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_reporting_date)
    info_name = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_name"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_name)
    info_email = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_email"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_email)
    info_id = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_id"]'))).text 
    lst.append(info_id)
    info_location = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_location"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_location)
    info_country = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_country"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_country)
    info_region = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_region"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_region)
    info_subregion = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_subregion"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_subregion)
    info_latitude = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_latitude"]'))).text
    lst.append(info_latitude)
    info_longitude = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_longitude"]'))).text 
    lst.append(info_longitude)
    info_elevation = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_seehoehe"]'))).text 
    lst.append(info_elevation)
    info_incline = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_incline"]'))).text 
    lst.append(info_incline)
    info_aspect = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_aspect"]'))).text 
    lst.append(info_aspect)  
    
    data_entry_date = info_date
    lst_total_info_date.append(data_entry_date)
    data_entry__reporting_date = info_reporting_date
    lst_total_info_reporting_date.append(data_entry__reporting_date)
    data_entry_name = info_name
    lst_total_info_name.append(data_entry_name)
    data_entry_email = info_email
    lst_total_info_email.append(data_entry_email)
    data_entry_id = info_id
    lst_total_info_id.append(data_entry_id)
    data_entry_location = info_location
    lst_total_info_location.append(data_entry_location)
    data_entry_country = info_country
    lst_total_info_country.append(data_entry_country)
    data_entry_region = info_region
    lst_total_info_region.append(data_entry_region)
    data_entry_subregion = info_subregion
    lst_total_info_subregion.append(data_entry_subregion)
    data_entry_latitude = info_latitude
    lst_total_info_latitude.append(data_entry_latitude)
    data_entry_longitude = info_longitude
    lst_total_info_longitude.append(data_entry_longitude)
    data_entry_elevation = info_elevation
    lst_total_info_elevation.append(data_entry_elevation)
    data_entry_incline = info_incline
    lst_total_info_incline.append(data_entry_incline)
    data_entry_aspect = info_aspect
    lst_total_info_aspect.append(data_entry_aspect)
    
    
    #Click on column
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, url_lawis_list_item0))).click()
    #scroll down once
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.DOWN)


driver.close()
    
#combined list of all data entries for dataframe 
lst_total = [lst_total_info_date, lst_total_info_reporting_date, lst_total_info_name, lst_total_info_email, lst_total_info_id,
                lst_total_info_location, lst_total_info_country, lst_total_info_region, lst_total_info_subregion, lst_total_info_latitude, lst_total_info_longitude,
                lst_total_info_elevation, lst_total_info_incline, lst_total_info_aspect]
    
    
    # Initialise empty Dataframe with column names 
import numpy as np
df0 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((100, 14)))
df0.columns = ['Observation Date', 'Reporting Date', 'Name', 'E-Mail', 'Profile-ID', 'Place', 'Country', 'Region', 'Subregion', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Elevation', 'Incline', 'Aspect']
# print(df0)
# print(df0.dtypes)


# Build Dataframe with Website data
df = pd.DataFrame(lst_total).transpose()
df.columns = ['Observation Date', 'Reporting Date', 'Name', 'E-Mail', 'Profile-ID', 'Place', 'Country', 'Region', 'Subregion', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Elevation', 'Incline', 'Aspect']
# print(df)

# Initialize Dataframe combined 0 and Data
dataframes = [df, df0]
df_total = pd.concat(dataframes)
df_total = df_total.reset_index()
# print(df_total)

df_total['Latitude'] = df_total['Latitude'].astype(float)
df_total['Longitude'] = df_total['Longitude'].astype(float)

df_total['lat_lon'] = list(zip(df_total['Latitude'], df_total['Longitude']))

search_input_lang_long = Feature(geometry=Point([47.6236, 14.346]))

c = df_total.loc[0:4, 'lat_lon'].to_list()

f1 = Feature(geometry=Point(c[0]))
f2 = Feature(geometry=Point(c[1]))
f3 = Feature(geometry=Point(c[2]))
f4 = Feature(geometry=Point(c[3]))
f5 = Feature(geometry=Point(c[4]))

fc = FeatureCollection([f1, f2, f3, f4, f5])

print(json.dumps(nearest_point(search_input_lang_long ,fc), indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
      47.64627,
      14.19269
    ],
    "type": "Point"
  },
  "properties": {
    "distanceToPoint": 17.221480383420726,
    "featureIndex": 0
  },
  "type": "Feature"
}
```

If you want the part to 'drop into' your existing code just copy the bit at the end here:

```
df_total['Latitude'] = df_total['Latitude'].astype(float)
df_total['Longitude'] = df_total['Longitude'].astype(float)

df_total['lat_lon'] = list(zip(df_total['Latitude'], df_total['Longitude']))

search_input_lang_long = Feature(geometry=Point([47.6236, 14.346]))

c = df_total.loc[0:4, 'lat_lon'].to_list()

f1 = Feature(geometry=Point(c[0]))
f2 = Feature(geometry=Point(c[1]))
f3 = Feature(geometry=Point(c[2]))
f4 = Feature(geometry=Point(c[3]))
f5 = Feature(geometry=Point(c[4]))
```

Comment: I think this fixed it? I am getting new error codes now, which is ( I guess ) a good sign haha I just don't get why the whole thing is still not working, since my Function and inputs into the trufpy part is now, in my eyes, exactly the same as in the turfpy example from their website. I added the new errors in the original post ps. I don't know why I had the [] everywhere. I guess I thought I needed them somehow.

Comment: I don't have much time today (maybe later) but trying to run the new code it does 'something'.  In `df_lat_long` I see this: https://ibb.co/dGkWJjh.  So a couple of valid looking coordinates and then zeros.  Ask yourself if is this expected.  If it was me I'd look to get the data in that column correct before running anything else.   Are you using a Jupyter notebook?  If so make the first cell getting the data and just work on that.

Comment: No worries, you helped so much already! Thanks for that. 

I do believe, that the ouput is exactly as it should be, that's why I do not understand why it wouldn't work. I added more info up at the end, that might help understand a bit more why I am (trying of) doing it the way I am.

Comment: You are an absolute Legend! I am going to go through that and see what I screwed up in comparison to yours <3

Answer (score 0):

If `[[df_total.at[0, 'Latitude'], df_total.at[0, 'Longitude']]` works for you, you can just do:

```
[float(df_total.at[0, 'Latitude'][0]), float(df_total.at[0, 'Longitude'][0])]
```

output: `[47.64627, 14.19269]`

Comment: I feel like this should work but for some reason I am getting another error code now:

Exception("coord must be GeoJSON Point or an Array of numbers")
Exception: coord must be GeoJSON Point or an Array of numbers

Comment: Can you provide a example constructor for your dataframe? It looks like you're storing objects, not just text or lists

Comment: I could add the complete test / samplecode if you like? I am basically finding elemts on a website via Selenium, converting them to text, then appending them to a list and those lists are then converted into the dataframe.

Comment: I just checked what data type is being stored in 'Latitude' and you are correct, its indeed Objects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work, but try it out:

```
df_total['Latitude'] = [str(s).replace('[','') for s in df_total['Latitude']

df_total['Latitude'] = [str(s).replace("'","") for s in df_total['Latitude']
```

Comment: That did not quite work sadly, my dataframe look like this when using your method: 
https://imgur.com/Neuz0Fg

Comment: Can you maybe provide datatype of the elements in df_total['Latitude'] ? You can do it using type().... Also updating answer try this and tell if it's working

Comment: I just did as you said and apparently I am storing "Objects" in the column Latitude. 

Here is a screenshot of the outputs now. https://imgur.com/TBYb66d

Comment: According to the ss, it works right? The first two rows in columns latitude and longitude are bring converted to strings....

Comment: Kind off yeah, I still need to somehow get rid of the ' ' around them since the function only takes inputs without any ' '

Comment: My error code now is : f1_lat_long = [float(df_total.at[0, 'Latitude'][0]), float(df_total.at[0, 'Longitude'][0])]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "'"

Comment: I suggest using the same method to replace the quotes... Have edited in answer